# FileLoadException at referenced assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF .NET 4.0 C# project that uses a TreeListView from Ricciolo (Ricciolo.Controls.TreeListView.dll) I have refrenced this dll that is in my "Release" folder. This file has the version 1.0.4643.**31163**

If I start debugging with visual studio (with option enabled to debug external code) I get the FileLoadException and the message that Version 1.0.4643.**31162** is required and was not found.

The Application starts well under Win 7 but **crashes under Win XP.**

Things I have done:

- Look if there is another version of the file: No
- Is the file registered in the GAC: No
- Change the version of the assembly with ILDASM: Same error
- Delete reference and reference the file again: Same error

Is there a possibilty to ignore this little version difference? Or is there another solution to run it under Windows XP?

Thanks for your help.

Max

[image: Call Stack]

Comment: Can you show us a stack trace from one of the crashes on Windows XP?

Comment: Contains the image the information you asked for?

Comment: @Max It would be nice if you posted stacktrace in English. Anyway, more likely that external dll is using some library, that windows XP misses.

Comment: Hmm, yeah my German is rusty. I only took a few years in high school. :-) A copy and paste of English text would be more helpful indeed. But from what I can decipher from the exception message, perhaps you need to add a manifest to the application so that it can link to version 6 of the common controls? Have you asked the distributor of the third-party control what its system requirements are? Does it support XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ignore version differences with [Assembly Binding Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
An example is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).